# how do you make it so when you press a key something will happen

Tags: javascript

hello im new to java script, so i kind of have  no knowledge of it yet to be specific im a newbie.
im using an engine called rpgboss which uses javascript.

im don't know if anyone here ever seen it / used it to be specific.

i'm trying to make this function in the game where when you press W a npc called dragon [a mount to be understandable]

will come to the player [or by it] but i only go this far.

> "keys"         : "w"

"on_keydown"   : true

i found this on a site, sept instead of true it has functions() i don't know how to finish it. since the javascript is probably slightly different on rpgboss

edit: didn't expect to get so many thumb downs in on question?
EDIT2: sorry guess i went overboard with the newbie thing..  i guess i was just being honest... sorry.c

Comment: Use javascript keydown event listener for this. Find more here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

Comment: @Nitheesh They are not programming for the browser.

Comment: You may be getting downvotes due to your statement that you have no knowledge of JavaScript. Please use some tutorials before asking a question, so that we know how to help you. Otherwise all we can do is give you some code to copy/paste (which isn't what this site is for).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Sorry, I just realized my answer is for generic javascript. I am not sure how this would relate to rpgboss.  I've looked at their docs, and I guess they are still working on them.  I recommend you ask in the rpgboss forums.
  http://rpgboss.forumatic.com

---

You need to add a key listener to your dragon or to your window.  Also then tell the key listener what to do when different keys are pressed.
You can find the keycode for different keys here: http://keycode.info  - the code for W is 87.

You also need to make sure it doesn't run when the dragon can't come - like in a cut scene, or a chapter where the dragon isn't there.

You have some design decisions.  Either add the event listener to the window, and only activate the dragon when it is ready.  The other option is add the listener to the dragon when it is ready, and remove the listener when it dies/can't come/etc.

```
when dragon is created{
  dragon.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressedListener);
}


when dragon dies/inactive{
  dragon.removeEventListener("keypress", keyPressedListener);
}

keyPressedListener(e) {
   let key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
   if(key == 87){
      dragon.goToPlayer();
   }
}
```

Or another option:

```
window.addEventListener("keypress", keyPressedListener);

keyPressedListener(e) {
    let key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(key == 87){
      if(isDragonReady(){
        dragon.goToPlayer();
      }
    }
}
```

You need to make sure you don't call the dragon when there is no dragon object.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: thanks your probably right but i don't think theyre working on rpgboss anymore its been abandoned for awhile as i saw anyway. nobody really used it anymore. theres only a few new topics and most of them are from 2014 - 2015 0r 2013. but ok i guess i could try anyway

Comment: great.  I hope my answer also explained to you how to do key listeners in the future.

Comment: still not sure what a key listeners is. but i should get it eventually

Comment: webpages don't normally respond to key presses, or to mouse movement, of mouse clicks (unless the click is on a link, or a submit button) -  `addEventListener`  tells your page to listen for these key and mouse events - `addEventListener("keypress"`  tells it to listen to keypresses  and then you tell it what function to run when the keys are pressed.  So in this example I made a function `keyPressedListener(e)`  which responds when W (87)  is pressed.  Does that explain it?